# How to test google analytics in firefox browser?

Tags: google-analytics, firefox-addon, event-tracking, browser-addons

As a part of Google analytics testing, i am testing the events fired, page view hits, conversions, label etc.. in firefox browser.

I couldn't find great add-on's as i found in Google Chrome browser to test the attributes mentioned above .
Can you let me know if there is any way forward to test the google analytic's in Firefox browser?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, this question is probably best posted to Webmasters as it's not related to coding. Best of luck!

Comment: Good question ill look into it and let you know what I find. Can you link the google chrome addons you found helpful for this work?

Comment: Hi Noitidart and Nyen .. thank you.

Google Chrome addons are GA debugger,  GA network tab, Console tab that comes when i hit F+12.

Comment: Hi piyanaka can you provide links

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

The above link is for GA debugger extension.

I just managed to check the google analytics parameters in firefox.
Hope this helps.
Open firefox browser->Tools->WebDeveloper-> webConsole
You would be prompted with a seperate or autofitted window.
Then go to Tool Box options-> Enable google Chrome addon debugging in advanced settings.
Then check in the network tab. you would get all the query parameters as you see in google.
Please let me know if any concerns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above link is for GA debugger extension. I just managed to check the google analytics parameters in firefox. Hope this helps. Open firefox browser->Tools->WebDeveloper-> webConsole You would be prompted with a seperate or autofitted window. Then go to Tool Box options-> Enable google Chrome addon debugging in advanced settings. Then check in the network tab. you would get all the query parameters as you see in google. Please let me know if any concerns

Also make sure you switch on the GTM in preview and debug mode, so that the query parameters would be more readable

Comment: For future passersby, Tools->settings(f1)->advanced settings->enable... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox